# jquery dialog box remembers previous input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please help me. 
I have a form with multiple text inputs having different ids but same class as below

```
<input id="user_1" type="text" class="user-list" />
<input id="user_2" type="text" class="user-list" />
<input id="user_3" type="text" class="user-list" />
```

Now using the class definition I am calling the jquery dialog as below

```
$('.user-list').click(function(){
    $( "#user-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    tableOpen(this);    
});
```

Here user-form is a list of names as below

```
<div id="user-form" title="Select Employee" >
<table id="user-table">
<thead><th>Employee No</th><th>Name</th></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Employee-1 No</td><td>Employee-1 Name</td></tr>
<tr><td>Employee-1 No</td><td>Employee-1 Name</td></tr>
<tr><td>Employee-1 No</td><td>Employee-1 Name</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Now I use dialog to open the div element in a dialog box

```
$( "#user-form" ).dialog({
create: function() {       },  
autoOpen: false,
cache: false,
closeOnEscape: true,
height: 400,
width: 600,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    Cancel: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" );}
},
close: function() {}
});
```

Dialog box appears as expected. Now I add a click event to the user-table rows in tableOpen function for selecting users.

```
function tableOpen(selInput)
{
    alert($(selInput).id().text()+"first");
    $('#user-table tr').click( function() {
           alert($(selInput).id().text()+"second");
    });
    //some other function here from displaying the selected user to input field
}
```

Here the problem starts. The first time I select a user by clicking, both the alerts in tableOpen function execute only one time. But on subsequent clicking the first alert is shown only single time but the second alert also remembers the previous clicks and alert appears for all the previous times I have clicked.

Comment: Is your javascript in the same file as the html?  I had this exact same issue. It was fixed after I moved all javascript code to a .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function tableOpen(selInput)
{
    alert($(selInput).id().text()+"first");
    $('#user-table tr').unbind('click');
    $('#user-table tr').click( function() {
           alert($(selInput).id().text()+"second");
    });
    //some other function here from displaying the selected user to input field
}
```

Comment: Every time you click on `tableOpen` DOM will attach click event with ELEMENT

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved the day.

Comment: or you can use `$( "#user-table tr" ).on( "click", function() { //YOUR CODE });` outside the `tableOpen`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of multiple binding of the click event.
Two things you can do over here.

1. Move click binding out of the block put during at binding area
2. of use off on events

> ```
> $('#user-table tr').off('click').on('click', function() {
>     alert($(selInput).id().text()+"second");
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are exactly want to say but I tried it and I am getting three alerts (equal to number of rows in `#user-table`) for `second`.

```
$('#user-table tr').click( function() {
           alert($(selInput).id().text()+"second");
    });
```

You must use specific selector to call `click` event on the row.

e.g provide unique id for each row in `#user-table` and use that for calling `.click()`